# XPages Request Processing Lifecycle -where does the package go

Tags: xpages

I am trying to run the code in the XPages Request Processing Lifecycle.

The 3rd bit of code says

But I don't know how to put in a package that matches the defined structure....

```
Code 3: XSPPhaseListener java class (put in a package that matches defined structure)

package com.ibm.xsp.util;

import javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent;
import javax.faces.event.PhaseId;

/**
 * @author Tony McGuckin, IBM
 */
public class XSPPhaseListener implements javax.faces.event.PhaseListener {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
      return PhaseId.ANY_PHASE;
    }

    public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {
      if(event.getPhaseId().equals(PhaseId.RESTORE_VIEW)){
          System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Request:\tStarted...");
      }
      System.out.println(" ");
      System.out.println("Lifecycle:\tBefore Phase: " + event.getPhaseId());
    }

    public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {
      System.out.println("Lifecycle:\tAfter Phase: " + event.getPhaseId());
      System.out.println(" ");
      if(event.getPhaseId().equals(PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE)){
        System.out.println("Request:\tCompleted.");
        System.out.println(" ");
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's just a peculiar way of talking about the Java package - it's probably best to create a class in your own package ("com.company") instead of IBM's namespace. It wouldn't hurt anything to copy the package name he has there, but it's good practice. Then just make sure that you use that new full class name ("com.company.XSPPhaseListener") when you go to add it to the Faces Config.

Comment: Also, see XPages OpenLog Logger project on OpenNTF, which has a PhaseListener in the NSF version. I use that to intercept and log out errors.